# Es posible hacer commit a un archivo especifico?

Tags: git

nueva con del uso de git.
Estoy utilizando visual studio como mi editor de codigo y tengo varios archivos guardados

Es posible hacer commit a un archivo especifico? tengo varios archivos pendientes por hacer commit ?
o cada vez que modifico un archivo tengo que hacer commit de dicho archivo?

No puedo ir modificando multiples archivos y cuando quiera hacer commit selecciono el archivo

```
Ejemplo1.js >f1 commit
Ejemplo99.js > f1 commit
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas trabajando con algún cliente de git (como smartgit, github desktop, etc) o con algún pluggin para tu ide?

Comment: Si como dice @Alejo es a traves del ide , suelen tener la opcion al hacer click derecho sobre el fichero

Comment: no, VS Code y con las opciones que ya tiene incorporada de git

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si trabajas por medio de la línea de comandos primero deberías agregar todos tus archivos pendientes con:

```
git add .
```

Posterior si haces un `git status` vas a notar que ahora tus archivos aparecen así:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
    new file:    file1.foo
    new file:    file2.foo
```

Finalmente si solo deseas hacer commit de `file1.foo` debería ser de esta forma:

```
git commit -m "Aquí tu mensaje del commit" file1.foo
```

Si ahora ejecutas nuevamente un `git status` notarás como dicho archivo se movió y solo queda `file2.foo`

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
    new file:    file2.foo
```

Adicionalmente puedes leer mas sobre el comando `git add` y del comando `git commit` agregando el flag `--help` el cual te abrirá un archivo en tu navegador con información al respecto

Answer (score 1):

Los commit en git representan "sets de cambios", puede ser un archivo, o varios.

Por lo general la regla es agrupar en un mismo commit, cambios relacionados entre sí, para que si llegado el caso tienes que revertir a determinado commit, represente la funcionalidad grabada en ese momento.

Para agregar de a un archivo al "stage" (etapa previa al commit) puedes hacer `git add ruta/al/archivo`

O bien el "modo interactivo": `git add -p`

Irá archivo por archivo, cambio por cambio, preguntando si agregar al stage. Todo cambio que le digas que "sí", entrará en el commit cuando lo hagas.

También se puede hacer `git add -p ruta/al/archivo` . Esto es muy útil si por ejemplo en un mismo archivo cambiaste varias cosas pero solo quieres commitear algunas